# Nested query in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to learn GraphQL and I think I may be misunderstanding something.  I want to be able to given a brand and a page, get some information back.  I also need to be able to query for a brand and get all pages.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
query {
     base(brand: "somebrand") {
      brand
      pages(route: "/") {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

So i wrote a schema like

```
type Page {
  name: String
  route: String 
}

type Base {
  brand: String
  pages: [Page]
}

type Query {
  base(brand: String): Base
  pages(route: String): Page
}
```

I get an error like Unknown argument "route" on field "pages" of type "base"

Comment: As the error indicates, you haven't defined an argument named `route` for the field `pages` on your `Base` type. You've only defined that argument on the `pages` field of your `Query` type.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you could define arguments on the field level, It though you needed queries for it.
So it's correct to do something like
```type Base {
  brand: String
  pages(route: String): [Page]
}
```
?

Comment: Yes. `Query` and `Mutation` are just types, the only special thing about them is that they serve as the root or entry point to your schema. Beyond that, anything you can do with a "regular" type and its fields, you can do with `Query` and `Mutation` and vice versa.